# What is the Mod Power Requirement?

Tags: remnant-2

Now I have completed the tutorial boss I have the chance to craft a mod for my weapon. Here is one of the options.

[image: Healing Shot - Weapon Mod - Mod power requirement 600]

This one has a 'Mod Power Requirement' of 600. What is this requirement and how do I know if I meet that requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mod Power Requirement is how much mod power you need in order to activate the equipped mod.

This is displayed as a light grey background on your weapon.

I just activated my mod and it's emptied the mod power. See a small grey background on the right of the UI.

[image: Black background with no grey]

Then I start shooting targets to cause damage and regenerate my mod power.

[image: Some mod power]

[image: Nearly full mod power]

Once this bar is full, the mod becomes available for use again.

[image: Full mod power, mod marked with a 1]

When you've unlocked the Spirit core trait, you can boost this with trait points to increase the rate of mod power generation.